# Set Array as Public Attribute

Tags: php, class

```
class Student{

$db_fields = array('id','firstname','lastname')

}
```

Is there any way to set $db_fields array into a public variable/attribute without typing it manually like:

```
class Student{

    $db_fields = array('id','firstname','lastname')

    public $id;
    public $firsname;
    public $last;
}
```

?

I'm trying to set it using foreach but I can't make it done.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Student{

    public $db_fields;

    public $id;
    public $firsname;
    public $last;

    public function __construct($data){
        $this->db_fields = $data;
    }
}

$students = new Student(array('id','firstname','lastname'));
```

You can set it this way .. 
or this way..

```
  class Student{

        public $db_fields;

        public $id;
        public $firsname;
        public $last;

        public function set_db_fields($data){
            $this->db_fields = $data;
        }
    }

    $students = new Student();
    $students->set_db_fields(array('id','firstname','lastname'));
```

The idea is when you call that class to set Those variables with some function..
1st way is to use the constructor and 2nd way is to write 1 function only for that..

The 3rd way is as @PLB replayed with magic functions.

Comment: I mean is I dont want to set public $id; public $firsname;public $last;
i just want to set the array fields to be public variables.

Comment: @arjay0601 Just to clarify: you want to do something like: `$instanceOfStudent->id` and it returned associated value of key `id` in array: `$db_fields = array('id'=> 1, ...)`?

Comment: @PLB has wrote the correct way.. 
How ever I usually am against such methods to add variables which don't exists at the class.. 1st your code will be very deficult for understandable from other developers and 2nd if for some reason your code skip 1 of those varialbes any class function which depend on it will fail because it won't exist at all..

Comment: @PLB that's not what I wanted.
For example I only have $db_fields = array('id','firstname','lastname') inside class.
is there any way that db_fields will turn in into public variables?
the id will become public $id inside the class without really typing it.

Comment: @arjay0601 in your case of array (id,firstname,lastname) are array values and if you set them (id=>1,firstname=>2,lastname=>3) they are keys with values 1,2,3 .. .
You have to use one strict way to add them to your class .. 
So at least write them as keys ..

Comment: @Svetlio

So is it possible the id,firstname and last inside array will be converted into "public $id","public $firstname" and "public $lastname" inside the class? I want the class to read them as public variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use magic method [`__get`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and [`__set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) (These methods are used to access inaccessible variables of instance. You can get further information in documentation) in your class `Student`.

```
public function __get($name) {
    return $this->{$name};
}

public function __set($name, $value){
    $this->{$name} = $value;
}
```

Now you can use it:

```
$obj = new Student();
$obj->db_fields = array(1,2,3); //Assign private variable.
var_dump($obj->db_fields); //Get private variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to access an array's variable is through the array (to my knowledge) as such:

```
$db_fields = array('id' => 5,'firstname' => 'Paul', 'lastname' => 'Doe');
echo $db_fields->id; // would print 5.
```

What you're saying you want is:

```
$db_fields = array('id' => 5,'firstname' => 'Paul', 'lastname' => 'Doe');
echo $id; // would print 5 but that is not possible
```

The only instance where this works is if the array you're talking about is $_POST and $_GET with register globals, but to my knowledge it is not possible to do this with any array (and in fact it is usually not recommended to do it even with the $_POST and $_GET arrays).

**EDIT:**

You can actually use the extract() function on your array.

```
$db_fields = array('id' => 5,'firstname' => 'Paul', 'lastname' => 'Doe');
extract($db_fields);
echo $id; // if I'm not mistaken, that should work
```